# Images don't appear - django ckeditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I upload image in ckeditor but it didn't appear 'cause path to image is

http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/hello-23-1547897944/uploads/2019/01/19/southside.jpg

But image is uploading to the folder:
[image]

[image]
[image]

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'contact',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

**models.py:**

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, db_index=True)
```

**I think that problem is in settings.py**

*Sorry, my English isn't well but i hope that u understand my question.*

Comment: Do you define the MEDIA_URL and the MEDIA_ROOT in your setting file?

Comment: No, but do I need?

Comment: Yes, you can find good information about that in below link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: i did it now I have a warning in console:

Comment: The joined path (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\yn\blog\media\uploads\2019\01\19\southside.jpg) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\yn\blog\media\)
Bad Request: /ckeditor/upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only add:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to my urls.py and it works!